# How to flush Wildfly memory in web console

Tags: memory-management, wildfly

I've been told that, on Wildfly 8's web console, there is a way to flush memory, is this true? I've been looking everywhere inside the console, and nothing seems remotely close to a memory flush feature.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "flush memory"?

Comment: They were wrong, they meant flush connections on the datasources option. Case closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no question here, just a misunderstanding: they didn't remember well, they meant flush connections in the datasources option of the console.

Thanks.